# Distributed learning in Tensorflow seq2seq tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, multi-gpu

I followed the tutorial on Tensorflow seq2seq module, specifically the Neural Machine Translation one: https://google.github.io/seq2seq/nmt/

It's working except for it's only utilizing one GPU out of the two available (the cluster assigned me gpus 5 and 6, and it's utilizing only 6). Here's a snapshot of nvidia-smi command output.

[Snapshot of nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Ofa.png)

It says the following in the aforementioned tutorial under "Training":

Distributed Training is supported out of the box using tf.learn. Cluster Configurations can be specified using the TF_CONFIG environment variable, which is parsed by the RunConfig. Refer to the Distributed Tensorflow Guide for more information.

I've searched a lot of resources and none of them have clear instructions on what I need to adjust in the code for this to work. Please advise.

Basically I'm asking:

(1) What should be the values of TF_CONFIG? And how can I know them?
(2) How should I edit train.py?

train.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# Copyright 2017 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""Main script to run training and evaluation of models.
"""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import os
import tempfile

import yaml

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import learn_runner
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import run_config
from tensorflow import gfile

from seq2seq import models
from seq2seq.contrib.experiment import Experiment as PatchedExperiment
from seq2seq.configurable import _maybe_load_yaml, _create_from_dict
from seq2seq.configurable import _deep_merge_dict
from seq2seq.data import input_pipeline
from seq2seq.metrics import metric_specs
from seq2seq.training import hooks
from seq2seq.training import utils as training_utils

tf.flags.DEFINE_string("config_paths", "",
                       """Path to a YAML configuration files defining FLAG
                       values. Multiple files can be separated by commas.
                       Files are merged recursively. Setting a key in these
                       files is equivalent to setting the FLAG value with
                       the same name.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("hooks", "[]",
                       """YAML configuration string for the
                       training hooks to use.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("metrics", "[]",
                       """YAML configuration string for the
                       training metrics to use.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("model", "",
                       """Name of the model class.
                       Can be either a fully-qualified name, or the name
                       of a class defined in `seq2seq.models`.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("model_params", "{}",
                       """YAML configuration string for the model
                       parameters.""")

tf.flags.DEFINE_string("input_pipeline_train", "{}",
                       """YAML configuration string for the training
                       data input pipeline.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("input_pipeline_dev", "{}",
                       """YAML configuration string for the development
                       data input pipeline.""")

tf.flags.DEFINE_string("buckets", None,
                       """Buckets input sequences according to these length.
                       A comma-separated list of sequence length buckets, e.g.
                       "10,20,30" would result in 4 buckets:
                       <10, 10-20, 20-30, >30. None disabled bucketing. """)
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("batch_size", 16,
                        """Batch size used for training and evaluation.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("output_dir", None,
                       """The directory to write model checkpoints and summaries
                       to. If None, a local temporary directory is created.""")

# Training parameters
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("schedule", "continuous_train_and_eval",
                       """Estimator function to call, defaults to
                       continuous_train_and_eval for local run""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("train_steps", None,
                        """Maximum number of training steps to run.
                         If None, train forever.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("eval_every_n_steps", 1000,
                        "Run evaluation on validation data every N steps.")

# RunConfig Flags
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("tf_random_seed", None,
                        """Random seed for TensorFlow initializers. Setting
                        this value allows consistency between reruns.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("save_checkpoints_secs", None,
                        """Save checkpoints every this many seconds.
                        Can not be specified with save_checkpoints_steps.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("save_checkpoints_steps", None,
                        """Save checkpoints every this many steps.
                        Can not be specified with save_checkpoints_secs.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("keep_checkpoint_max", 5,
                        """Maximum number of recent checkpoint files to keep.
                        As new files are created, older files are deleted.
                        If None or 0, all checkpoint files are kept.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours", 4,
                        """In addition to keeping the most recent checkpoint
                        files, keep one checkpoint file for every N hours of
                        training.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_float("gpu_memory_fraction", 1.0,
                      """Fraction of GPU memory used by the process on
                      each GPU uniformly on the same machine.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_boolean("gpu_allow_growth", False,
                        """Allow GPU memory allocation to grow
                        dynamically.""")
tf.flags.DEFINE_boolean("log_device_placement", False,
                        """Log the op placement to devices""")


FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS

def create_experiment(output_dir):
  """
  Creates a new Experiment instance.
  Args:
    output_dir: Output directory for model checkpoints and summaries.
  """

  config = run_config.RunConfig(
      tf_random_seed=FLAGS.tf_random_seed,
      save_checkpoints_secs=FLAGS.save_checkpoints_secs,
      save_checkpoints_steps=FLAGS.save_checkpoints_steps,
      keep_checkpoint_max=FLAGS.keep_checkpoint_max,
      keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=FLAGS.keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours,
      gpu_memory_fraction=FLAGS.gpu_memory_fraction)
  config.tf_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = FLAGS.gpu_allow_growth
  config.tf_config.log_device_placement = FLAGS.log_device_placement

  train_options = training_utils.TrainOptions(
      model_class=FLAGS.model,
      model_params=FLAGS.model_params)
  # On the main worker, save training options
  if config.is_chief:
    gfile.MakeDirs(output_dir)
    train_options.dump(output_dir)

  bucket_boundaries = None
  if FLAGS.buckets:
    bucket_boundaries = list(map(int, FLAGS.buckets.split(",")))

  # Training data input pipeline
  train_input_pipeline = input_pipeline.make_input_pipeline_from_def(
      def_dict=FLAGS.input_pipeline_train,
      mode=tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

  # Create training input function
  train_input_fn = training_utils.create_input_fn(
      pipeline=train_input_pipeline,
      batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
      bucket_boundaries=bucket_boundaries,
      scope="train_input_fn")

  # Development data input pipeline
  dev_input_pipeline = input_pipeline.make_input_pipeline_from_def(
      def_dict=FLAGS.input_pipeline_dev,
      mode=tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.EVAL,
      shuffle=False, num_epochs=1)

  # Create eval input function
  eval_input_fn = training_utils.create_input_fn(
      pipeline=dev_input_pipeline,
      batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
      allow_smaller_final_batch=True,
      scope="dev_input_fn")


  def model_fn(features, labels, params, mode):
    """Builds the model graph"""
    model = _create_from_dict({
        "class": train_options.model_class,
        "params": train_options.model_params
    }, models, mode=mode)
    return model(features, labels, params)

  estimator = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(
      model_fn=model_fn,
      model_dir=output_dir,
      config=config,
      params=FLAGS.model_params)

  # Create hooks
  train_hooks = []
  for dict_ in FLAGS.hooks:
    hook = _create_from_dict(
        dict_, hooks,
        model_dir=estimator.model_dir,
        run_config=config)
    train_hooks.append(hook)

  # Create metrics
  eval_metrics = {}
  for dict_ in FLAGS.metrics:
    metric = _create_from_dict(dict_, metric_specs)
    eval_metrics[metric.name] = metric

  experiment = PatchedExperiment(
      estimator=estimator,
      train_input_fn=train_input_fn,
      eval_input_fn=eval_input_fn,
      min_eval_frequency=FLAGS.eval_every_n_steps,
      train_steps=FLAGS.train_steps,
      eval_steps=None,
      eval_metrics=eval_metrics,
      train_monitors=train_hooks)

  return experiment


def main(_argv):
  """The entrypoint for the script"""

  # Parse YAML FLAGS
  FLAGS.hooks = _maybe_load_yaml(FLAGS.hooks)
  FLAGS.metrics = _maybe_load_yaml(FLAGS.metrics)
  FLAGS.model_params = _maybe_load_yaml(FLAGS.model_params)
  FLAGS.input_pipeline_train = _maybe_load_yaml(FLAGS.input_pipeline_train)
  FLAGS.input_pipeline_dev = _maybe_load_yaml(FLAGS.input_pipeline_dev)

  # Load flags from config file
  final_config = {}
  if FLAGS.config_paths:
    for config_path in FLAGS.config_paths.split(","):
      config_path = config_path.strip()
      if not config_path:
        continue
      config_path = os.path.abspath(config_path)
      tf.logging.info("Loading config from %s", config_path)
      with gfile.GFile(config_path.strip()) as config_file:
        config_flags = yaml.load(config_file)
        final_config = _deep_merge_dict(final_config, config_flags)

  tf.logging.info("Final Config:\n%s", yaml.dump(final_config))

  # Merge flags with config values
  for flag_key, flag_value in final_config.items():
    if hasattr(FLAGS, flag_key) and isinstance(getattr(FLAGS, flag_key), dict):
      merged_value = _deep_merge_dict(flag_value, getattr(FLAGS, flag_key))
      setattr(FLAGS, flag_key, merged_value)
    elif hasattr(FLAGS, flag_key):
      setattr(FLAGS, flag_key, flag_value)
    else:
      tf.logging.warning("Ignoring config flag: %s", flag_key)

  if FLAGS.save_checkpoints_secs is None \
    and FLAGS.save_checkpoints_steps is None:
    FLAGS.save_checkpoints_secs = 600
    tf.logging.info("Setting save_checkpoints_secs to %d",
                    FLAGS.save_checkpoints_secs)

  if not FLAGS.output_dir:
    FLAGS.output_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

  if not FLAGS.input_pipeline_train:
    raise ValueError("You must specify input_pipeline_train")

  if not FLAGS.input_pipeline_dev:
    raise ValueError("You must specify input_pipeline_dev")

  learn_runner.run(
      experiment_fn=create_experiment,
      output_dir=FLAGS.output_dir,
      schedule=FLAGS.schedule)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
  tf.app.run()
```

Comment: can you post a link to the documentation for "Distributed Training is supported out of the box using tf.learn" and "TF_CONFIG environment variable" ?  Also, a link to the "train.py"?

Comment: Hi @JacobHolloway , I added the code to the post and gave instructions on how to reach that part of the tutorial which talks about distributed learning. I'm not allowed to post any more links due to reputation points.